# CakePHP 3.x How to detect the specific Flash messages?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 8 different Flash elements.

4 of them are like these:

`growl_success
growl_error
growl_info
growl_warning`

The other 4 are:

`alert_success
alert_error
alert_info
alert_warning`

I want to make it flexible so that at the Controller end, I can freely switch between any of these 8.

The problem is I want the `<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>` to be at different places in the `layout.ctp` for `growl` type messages compared to `alert` type messages.

Is there a way I can do something like

`<?php if ($this->Flash->startsWith('growl') : ?>
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?php endif; ?>`

or

`<?= $this->Flash->renderGrowl(); ?>`

Comment: How you manage to use Growl on flash? mind to share snippet of the *.ctp flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the 'key' options when setting the message

in your controller

```
$this->Flash->alert_success(__('Alert success!!'), [
                'plugin' => 'PluginName', 'key' => 'alert']);
```

or alternatively

```
$this->Flash->growl_success(__('The project has been saved.'), [
                'plugin' => 'PluginName', 'key' => 'growl']);
```

in your layout in two different positions

```
<?= $this->Flash->render('growl'); ?>

...

<?= $this->Flash->render('alert'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out myself eventually. Good job~!

Comment: When you post a question and then figure the answer out yourself, it's good form to come back and post the answer. This makes it available to others who may come later, saves others from wasting time writing an answer you don't need, and allows people the opportunity to add any useful comments they might have about limitations of, or ways to improve, your solution.

Comment: I was about to post back the answer and then I saw the similar answer posted. I did edit it to make it better.